# Countermeasures against firearm disarms

Tags: firearms

Some of the countermeasures I can typically think of include gaining distance as much as possible. But this is the most naive thing to carry out. Even employing modifications to the grip and practicing disarms with a prop and friend would benefit.

*How should you prevent an attacker from trying to push the gun out the way if you are cornered? What to do if the attacker tries to "dis-chamber" the round?* (or hold the slide and push it out the way while you fire)

Comment: The problem is, right now, I don't have confidence in anyone's strategies for grappling range pistol fights (I assume you're talking about pistols, not rifles or shotguns). It requires pressure testing, similar to how MMA people train. But I haven't seen a lot of that going on out there. Most firearm combat training tends to be situational, not very "live", somewhat compliant. I don't see realistic training going on. But that would be my prescription to answer this question. Practice it, with partners who are trying all they can to defeat you. Obviously use a fake gun that maybe squirts dye.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Tried that with a cap-gun. So, we can't really go 100% all out. But, I couldn't get disarmed under 25 seconds. (Didn't want to break my finger and we were not allowed to pull the trigger because of the smell of the cap-smoke).  I still got pretend shots in center mass.

Comment: @SteveWeigand I just remembered that if you hold the slide and grip it gives you more control over the gun.(sure you'll get messed up, but its better than being messed up forever) This can make you last so long.

Comment: Adding "rules of engagement" to your question will make it better. What is the situation? e.g Will you shoot his leg if you tell him to put his hands on his head and he refuse?

Comment: This is interesting because it is usually the attacker that has the gun, not the defender. When I first saw this question, I was thinking "why are you trying to attack someone?". Of course, I since actually read the question and see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

1. Hold the gun with two hands, not one hand-gangster-style.
2. Gain some distance if possible. Don't get close to him until you -
3. Order him to turn around and sit, with his hands on his head. Shoot the ground or his leg if necessary and possible, If you can't -
4. Be ready to kick him away from you.

Answer (score 3):

*If someone pointed a firearm at a target, they should be fully prepared to fire upon said target.* This renders any martial disarm imporbable.

Any offensive move from the target would be met by a round, generally aimed at the centre of mass. Shooting limbs is much harder and can lead to unwanted collateral damage as the round has to go somewhere behind the target. Note that different rules of engagements (ROE) do exist: LEO, special forces on missions, sicarios, … which will reflect what the shooter does from trying to prevent lose of life to "I was told to kill you, bye".

Martial art disarms are either play fighting or lucky breaks. In a few edge cases, where the ROE allow it, it is easier for a good martial artist to disarm/kill someone with a gun: [We have all seen Dan Inosanto's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwCl9bfz-8Y). Now, I would like to see the same video with Clint Eastwood (or any other [fast draw chapion](https://truewestmagazine.com/fastest-gun-hollywood/) vs a noob in knife fighting: can a noob cover 21 feet in under .8 of a second? …

As an example of an actual fight of guns vs unarmed: [Gates Of Fire](https://www.michaelyon-online.com/gates-of-fire.htm) ***⚠ Graphic content*** Where a squad of marines get ambushed by some insurgents in Iraq. One of the marines ends up having to fight an armed insurgent without a firearm.

> The marine wins due to luck and much better training.

Comment: Can the knife-welder know how to use his knife? Better stab in the right spot. Or else, he may still get shot.

Comment: @TravisWells Dan Inosanto attacks an untrained in gun craft person. So no, the knife welder cannot know how to use their knife beyond the obvious basics. *The point I was trying to make is that anyone with skill can easily defeat someone without.*